# Sum of trade by all the companies in MySQL [delete]

Tags: mysql, sql

I want to find out the company with the maximum capital[price*quantity] (Including all entries for that company in the whole table). Any suggestions?

I've done this:

```
SELECT symbol, SUM(amount*price) AS total
FROM orders
GROUP BY symbol
```

Comment: Great. Did you try anything?

Comment: What's the expected result if two different symbols have the same, maximum result?

Comment: Most people here want formatted text, not images.

Comment: Yes I tried multiplying two columns for the similar ids. But how to find max. from that table is an issue!

Comment: @jarlh both of them should be displayed!

Comment: Step 1: Do a `GROUP BY`!

Comment: Can I combine both the steps in one statement?

Comment: Yes, but beginners should take it step by step and verify each step's result.

Comment: `SELECT symbol,SUM(amount*price) AS total FROM orders GROUP BY symbol` I have done this

Comment: How can I further find the symbol with Max. total now?

Comment: Oops, I can't remember if MySQL supports FETCH FIRST WITH TIES... Add `ORDER BY total DESC FETCH FIRST 1 ROW WITH TIES` at the end and see what happens.

Answer (score 2):

If `FETCH FIRST WITH TIES` is supported:

```
SELECT symbol, SUM(amount*price) AS total
FROM orders
GROUP BY symbol
ORDER BY total DESC
FETCH FIRST 1 ROW WITH TIES
```

If not:

```
SELECT symbol, SUM(amount*price) AS total
FROM orders
GROUP BY symbol
HAVING SUM(amount*price) = (SELECT SUM(amount*price) AS total
                            FROM orders
                            GROUP BY symbol
                            ORDER BY total DESC
                            LIMIT 1)
```

Comment: can you please upvote the question because of this question i'm not able to raise more questions.It'll be a great help!

Answer (score 1):

Your query should look like this.

```
SELECT symbol,SUM(amount*price) AS total FROM orders GROUP BY symbol order by total desc limit 1;
```

I am adding limit 1 as you want to find out the company with maximum capital.

Comment: Will not include both rows in case of a tie.

Comment: thats true @jarlh